# Is it possible to create resources in azure in multiple subscriptions using single pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a requirement to create resources based on the text file uploaded to the azure devops repos by my client. My client wants to keep it minimal and need only one file to be updated and single pipeline to deploy resources to multiple subscriptions (dev, test, prod).

Text file preview

[image]

I am able to read this file and create resources using powershell (using loop) in single subscription. I am not sure how to create single pipeline to read this file and create resources in multiple subscriptions.

**Note: TargetSubscription is a service connection.**

Is it possible? If yes, what is the best way to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am open to use a yaml pipeline as well if there is an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If TargetSubscription is a service connection, I assume each service connection has necessary access in the relevant Subscription. Since you already said you have a PowerShell code, you can use Connect-AzAccount for every new service connection:

```
$SecureStringPwd = $sp.PasswordCredentials.SecretText | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$pscredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $sp.AppId, $SecureStringPwd
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $pscredential -Tenant $tenantId
```

Azure Docs link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-8.1.0#password-based-authentication

Your Azure DevOps service connections need to have a relevant service principal in Azure side. If that service principal has permission to deploy resources (for example, Contributor RBAC on subscription), you can create your resources in that Subscription after you sign in with it.

Call the Connect-AzAccount every time you read a new Service Connection from the text file, and then the remaining of your script will run to create resources. Your sign in session should only see that specific Subscription.

You can create client secret on Azure side for each service principal. Then you can put this secret into Key Vault, get the value securely from Key Vault in your script and pass it as a parameter to $SecureStringPwd, as displayed above.

Comment: My service connection and service principal names are different. Could you please elaborate more on how to get this object in variable ($sp) in the code you shared. I do not have to create new service principal but use existing one attached with service connection. Please suggest.

Comment: Of course, you don't need to create a new one. That's just an example in Azure docs. Also, service connection and principal doesn't have to be the same name. But in the end they are connected to each other. If you are inside yml pipeline, use key vault task (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet) to get secrets. Or maybe use environment variables (not recommended!) if you are in a classical pipeline. Ignore $sp, you need to get client secret (.SecretText) and client id (.AppId).